How can I separate lines and circles using CV2
I am trying to separate lines and circles of the image below using morphology. To maintain circle I did it well, but for lines I really do not know how to do to remove the circles.
The Image Sample:

Code for just circles:
image = cv2.imread('sample.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = otsuThresholding(image) # Function that threshold the image

structuringElement = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (18, 18))
imageErode = cv2.erode(image, structuringElement)
openingCircles = cv2.dilate(imageErode, structuringElement)

plt.title("Circles")
plt.imshow(openingCircles, 'gray', vmax=255, vmin=0)
plt.show()

Just circles:

I already tried to remove the circles of the original image and then dilate, but it not works well, it ends up with holes in the middle of the lines, or it becomes so thick that it joins them together.

Show what you did to remove the circles: code and resulting image.

Can you post original image?

You might be better using HoughCircle() to find the circles.

Solve these two tasks independently of each other. No need to remove the circles before searching for lines.


detect the lines (for example HoughLines 2. estimate the real length and width of the lines (e.g. maximum length and median width) 3. replace the original image by drawing the detected and estimated lines on a black image.

